# Проблема в использовании static переменной в QT Creator с версией 5.9.9

Tags: c++, qt, static

сегодня столкнулся с проблемой в qt creator, использую 5.9.9 версию.
Проблема заключается в static переменной и в static методе моего класса(MainWindow).
Я создал public поле static и попытался init на месте. Но компилятор выдал ошибку non-const static data member must be initialized out of line. Сразу же я попробовал создать static setter и инициализировать static переменную в main до создания объекта, но это не помогло, поэтому решил обойти эту проблему созданием Global переменной, но компилятор выдавал ошибку.Прошу не судить строго, это мой первый вопрос и я новичок.
Приведу сразу исходники основные, которые связанны с проблемой

Mainwindow.hpp

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <fstream>
#include "Map.hpp"
#include "popup.hpp"
#include "form.hpp"


QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class MainWindow; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    ~MainWindow();

    void addNew(QString str); //new word in dictionary

    static void setMap(Map &&map)
    {
      map_ = std::move(map);
    }

private slots:

    void on_englishword_returnPressed(); //search

    void on_search_clicked(); //search

    void on_add_clicked();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;

    std::ifstream in; //txt stream

    std::fstream out; //txt stream

public:
   static Map map_;

private:
    PopUp * popUp; //notification

    Form * form; //confirmation window

};
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <string>
#include <QThread>
#include "List.hpp"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
      popUp(new PopUp),
      form(new Form)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  QPixmap bkgnd("/Users/gvgromov/Desktop/back.jpg");
  setWindowIcon(QIcon("/Users/gvgromov/Desktop/ic.jpg"));

  bkgnd = bkgnd.scaled(this->size(), Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio);
  QPalette palette;
  palette.setBrush(QPalette::Background, bkgnd); //background color/theme
  this->setPalette(palette);
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::addNew(QString str)
{
  std::string newStr = str.toStdString();
  out.open("/Users/gvgromov/Desktop/dict.txt",std::ios::app);
  try
  {
     map_.parse(newStr);
     out << "\r";
     out << newStr;
     out.close();
     popUp->setPopupText("Word and translate was added succesfully!");
     popUp->show();
  } catch (std::invalid_argument&ob)
  {
    popUp->setPopupText((QString::fromStdString(ob.what())));
    popUp->show();
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_englishword_returnPressed()
{
   on_search_clicked();
}

void MainWindow::on_search_clicked()
{
  List list;
  QString buff;
  buff = ui->englishword->text();
  try
  {
    QString temp = QString::fromStdString(map_.search(buff.toStdString()).toString());
    ui->translate->setText(temp);
  }
  catch (std::out_of_range &)
  {
    form->show();
  }
}

void MainWindow::on_add_clicked()
{
    addNew(ui->englishword->text());
}
```

main cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Map map("/Users/gvgromov/Desktop/dict.txt");
    MainWindow::setMap(std::move(map));
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Dictionary");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

map.cpp

```
#include "Map.hpp"
#include <stdexcept>
#include <fstream>

Map::Map() noexcept:
        root_(nullptr),
        count_(0)
{}

Map::Map(const char* url)
{
  std::ifstream in(url);
  while (!in.eof())
  {
    in >> *this;
  }
  in.close();
}

void Map::add(Pair &&pair)
{
  ptr node = std::make_shared<Node>(Node(std::move(pair)));
  if (!root_)
  {
    root_ = node;
    return;
  }
  ptr current = root_;
  while (current)
  {
    if (current->data_.first() == node->data_.first())
    {
      return;
    }
    if (current->data_.first() > node->data_.first() && current->left_)
    {
      current = current->left_;
      continue;
    } else if (current->data_.first() < node->data_.first() && current->right_)
    {
      current = current->right_;
      continue;
    }
    ++count_;
    if (current->data_.first() > node->data_.first())
    {
      current->left_ = node;
    } else if ((current->data_.first() < node->data_.first()))
    {
      current->right_ = node;
    }
    return;
  }
}

void Map::add(std::string &&word, List &&translate)
{
  Pair pair(std::move(word), std::move(translate));
  add(std::move(pair));
}


List &Map::search(const std::string &word)
{
  if (!root_)
  {
    throw std::out_of_range("Doesnt exist!");
  }
  ptr node = root_;
  while (node)
  {
    if (node->data_.first() == word)
    {
      return node->data_.second();
    }
    if (node->data_.first() > word)
    {
      if (node->left_)
      {
        node = node->left_;
        continue;
      }
    } else
    {
      if (node->right_)
      {
        node = node->right_;
        continue;
      }
    }
    throw std::out_of_range("Doesnt exist!");
  }
}

void Map::remove_root()
{
  if (!root_->left_ && !root_->right_)
  {
    root_.reset();
    --count_;
  }
  if ((!root_->right_ && root_->left_) || (root_->right_ && !root_->left_))
  {
    --count_;
    if (root_->left_)
    {
      root_ = std::move(root_->left_);
      return;
    }
    root_ = std::move(root_->right_);
    return;
  }
  ptr temp1 = minElement(root_->right_);//todo why without move
  std::string swipe = temp1->data_.first();
  remove(temp1->data_.first());
  root_->data_.first() = swipe;
  --count_;
}

void Map::remove(const std::string &word)
{
  if (root_->data_.first() == word)
  {
    remove_root();
    return;
  }
  ptr current = root_;
  ptr prev;
  while (current && current->data_.first() != word)
  {
    prev = current;
    if (current->data_.first() > word)
    {
      current = current->left_;
    } else
    {
      current = current->right_;
    }
  }
  if(!current)
  {
    throw std::invalid_argument("This word doesn't exist!");
  }
  if (!current->left_ && !current->right_)
  {
    if (prev->data_.first() > word)
    {
      prev->left_.reset();
    } else
    {
      prev->right_.reset();
    }
    --count_;
    return;
  }
  if ((!current->right_ && current->left_) || (current->right_ && !current->left_))
  {
    ptr temp1;
    if (!current->left_)
    {
      temp1 = std::move(current->right_);
    } else
    {
      temp1 = std::move(current->left_);
    }
    if (prev->data_.first() > word)
    {
      prev->left_ = temp1;
    } else
    {
      prev->right_ = temp1;
    }
    --count_;
    return;
  }
  ptr temp1 = std::move(minElement(current->right_)); //todo why with move
  std::string swipe = temp1->data_.first();
  remove(temp1->data_.first());
  current->data_.first() = swipe;
  --count_;
}

List &Map::operator[](std::string &word)
{
  return search(word);
}

void Map::parse(std::string &buffer)
{
  std::string key, translate;
  int pos = 0;
  if (buffer.front() == '\n')
  {
    buffer.erase(buffer.begin());
  }
  for (const auto &ch:buffer)
  {
    if (!isalpha(ch) && ch != ' ' && ch != '-')
    {
      key = buffer.substr(0, pos - 2);
      break;
    }
    pos++;
  }
  translate = buffer.substr(pos);
  List temp1;
  temp1.parser(translate);
  Pair temp(std::move(key), std::move(temp1));
  add(std::move(temp));
}

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Map &map)
{
  std::string buffer;
  getline(in, buffer, '\r');
  map.parse(buffer);
  return in;
}
```

И самое главное описание ошибки:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "MainWindow::map_", referenced from:
      MainWindow::setMap(Map&&) in main.o
      MainWindow::addNew(QString) in mainwindow.o
      MainWindow::on_search_clicked() in mainwindow.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Dictionary.app/Contents/MacOS/Dictionary] Error 1
00:27:56: Процесс «/usr/bin/make» завершился с кодом 2.
Ошибка при сборке/развёртывании проекта Dictionary (комплект: Desktop Qt 5.9.9 clang 64bit)
Во время выполнения этапа «Сборка»
```

Comment: `Map MainWindow::map_;` в cpp файл

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно перенести объявление `static Map map_;`
из заголовочного файла в файл класса (и соответственно реализацию `setMap(Map &&map)` тоже), тогда должно будет выполниться условие, на которое ругается компилятор. Я проверил, правда, не на clang, а на mingw.

Правда, не до конца понял, зачем используется именно статическая переменная, а не, например, переменная того же типа, которая инициализируется в конструкторе `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow(const char *url, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
```

в mainwindow.hpp

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(const char *url, QWidget *parent)
: QMainWindow(parent),
  ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
  map_(url)
{...
```

в mainwindow.cpp

```
MainWindow w("/Users/gvgromov/Desktop/dict.txt");
```

в main.cpp

Comment: Действительно работает, спасибо большое.Я так понимаю размещение static полей и переменных в cpp  это особенность с++?

Comment: Кроме объявления (декларации) статической переменной нужна ещё и инициализация, а в теле класса она не может производиться (как указано у вас в тексте вопроса). Если инициализировать её в заголовочном файле, то она будет инициализирована и в mainwindow.o, и в main.o. — ошибка multiple definition. Корректным будет, например, вариант, указанный выше Pavel Gridin.